# How to expand a file with MS-DOS' expand program

Tags: linux, debian

I want to expand a file with `expand` program, like MS-DOS, but in Debian Linux. How to do it without `wine` and other emulators?

The file I want to expand is `256COLOR.BM_` from the Windows 3.1 installation disks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

7-zip can expand such files; in Debian, install `p7zip-full`, then

```
7z l /path/to/256color.bm_
```

will show information about the file, and

```
7z x /path/to/256color.bm_
```

will decompress it.